# How to create a layout for an Android card game? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm pretty new to Android, and I am trying to create a certain card game.

My goal is to show the player cards (between 1-5 cards) face up,
and the rest of the players cards (same amount) face down.

My question is - how can I display the cards, and also add/remove cards?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can gave you an idea:

Create a LinearLayout (orientation vertical) and inside two realtive layout with weight = 0.5 for both.

Now that you have your screen splitted in two you can add your card directly via code. Create a card object that extend a ImageView and place it using the layout params with leftMargin (your x coord.) and topMargin (your y coord.)

Add your logic in the CardObject.